# PHP Session not timing out

Tags: php, session

I cant seem to get my session to time out.
see below very simple code.
The start button starts session and below prints id and time till timeout. I've set it to 5 seconds, which it does display, but if you wait for more than 5 seconds and refresh it still shows the id and 5 seconds. 
Am I missing something here?

```
<?php

echo <<<_END

<form method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="start" value="yes"/>
<input type="submit" value="Start session"/>
</form>
_END;

if (isset($_POST['start']))
{
session_start();
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 5);
ini_set('gc_probability', 100);
ini_set('gc_divisor', 100);
}

echo session_id();
echo "<br>";
echo ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime');

?>
```

Comment: THe session-id is the cookie that is set, and a discarded session would be restarted with the same id if your browser still sends the cookie. Try to _store_ something in the `$_SESSION`, and see if it is still there. Also, do the `ini_set`'s _before_ `session_start`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php):

`To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.`.

Comment: Yep. Has to be called on every page you want to use session variables, too, so putting it in an `if` statement isn't going to work here.

Answer (score 0):

by default in PHP Session data store in tmp directory
may be it time so small to phisically delete session temporary data.
Try to increase session maxlifetime.

(by default session delete by cron. Could it run the delete operation?)

Comment: To my knowledge old session files are not deleted by cron but actually by `session_start()`. On every `session_start()` there is a low chance that also the session garbage collector will be called and remove old session files. OP even configured the GC's behavior with `ini_set('gc_probability', 100); ini_set('gc_divisor', 100);`.

Comment: I also couldn't find any source for your claim that a too short `session_maxlifetime` may cause problems. Can you provide a source for us, please?

Answer (score 0):

`ini_set` is just change the setting for current page. Try put the code below outside `if`, at the top of the page, and you need to call `session_start` every time you deal with session.

```
<?php

ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 5);
ini_set('gc_probability', 100);
ini_set('gc_divisor', 100);
session_start();

echo <<<_END
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="start" value="yes"/>
<input type="submit" value="Start session"/>
</form>
_END;

if (isset($_POST['start']))
{
    $_SESSION['test'] = 'I should disappear on next request after 5 seconds';
}

echo $_SESSION['test'];

?>
```